# Emacs freezes using Sweave and ESS

Tags: ess

I am using Emacs + ESS + Sweave to write a document.  When I do multiline copy of noweb commands using M-w, switch to R buffer and execute them (C-y, RET), Emacs will sometimes freeze, forcing me to kill Emacs and start over.  This also happens with `C-c C-c`'ing of a text block.

EDIT: I am using Emacs 24.3.1, ESS 14.09, R 3.1.2.

EDIT: After some testing, the following file will reproduce this problem.  Specifically, the first chunk will cause Emacs to hang.  The only resolution is to first `C-g` then switch to the R buffer and `C-q C-c` to return full control.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, verbatim, geometry,amsmath,amssymb, natbib, float, enumerate, courier, underscore}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
library(ggplot2)
dat <- matrix(runif(100), nrow=10)
    cc <- apply(dat, 1, function(xx){
    sum(cos(xx))
})
@ 

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

<<>>=
bcc <- sapply(cc, function(xx){
    fft(xx)
})
@ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Next time it happens, do a `kill -USR2 <emacs-pid>` which will break most hangs and produce a backtrace. For extra info do `M-x` `profiler-start` when you start Emacs and `M-x` `profiler-report` after you kill.

Comment: It's a long trace.  Is there something specific you are looking for?

Comment: Something similar happens to me sometimes when I try to yank a shell buffer with a lot of text in it (a log of some sort), I think that it is either clipboard- or history-related. If you wait for a while (this isn't guaranteed to happen) but if you are up for experiment, some times it might pop up a `*Warnings*` buffer with a text about maximum undo steps exceeded. If that sounds familiar, I think it might make sense to file a bug to Emacs developers.

Comment: Does it happen when you `send-region` instead? I think it's `C-c C-r`, which should be available from a Rnw document.

Comment: This is weird.  It isn't related to tons of text, and does happen with `send-region` as well.  Actually, it seems that sending `\\w`apply() calls using one of {`C-c C-c`, `C-c C-r`, `M-w C-y`} seems to be what kills it.  Then it hangs at `starting evaluation`...

Comment: I should add that Sweave-ing the document doesn't produce a hang up, nor does manually entering calls that when yanked/sent would freeze.

Comment: Can you post a MWE that **sometimes** reproduces this?

Comment: It works fine for me. What version of Emacs and ESS are you using? I recall having a similar problem, but it was years ago now.

Comment: I'm using Emacs 24.3.1, ESS 14.09

Comment: Try updating ESS, thats quite a dated version the current stable is [18.10.2](https://ess.r-project.org/index.php?Section=download) or you can install the development version from [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/ess) with `M-x package-install ess`.